# UserControl not showing after applying style

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm in the making of a `usercontrol` library. Therefore I don't have `app.xaml` file nor `mainwindow.xaml`.

I imported (copied) a slider style from another WPF project. This `resource dictionary` is set to `page` and was working fine before but, as soon as I apply it to my slider then the control is not showing in VisualStudio as well as runtime. No errors are thrown.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPF.UserControls.CustomSlider"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF.UserControls"
         x:Name="CustomSliderControl"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="407" d:DesignWidth="127">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/WPFUserControls;component/Styles/BaseSliderStyle.xaml"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Slider x:Name="Hello" Style="{DynamicResource BaseSliderStyle}" Value="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, 
RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomSlider}}}" Minimum="0.0" Maximum="1.0"/>
</Grid>
```

And here is part of the slider style :

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF.UserControls">
<Style x:Key="BaseSliderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Static.Foreground}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource SliderHorizontal}"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource SliderVertical}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I may have miss something. Any hint ?

Thanks.

Comment: is WPFUserControls the name of your DLL/project ?

Comment: Check if the resources in <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Static.Foreground}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource SliderHorizontal}"/> are imported. Also check if SliderVertical is imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have added a reference to WPFUserControls.dll and try this:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WPFUserControls;component/Styles/BaseSliderStyle.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Slider x:Name="Hello" Style="{StaticResource BaseSliderStyle}" Value="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomSlider}}}" Minimum="0.0" Maximum="1.0"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Since I am using the `StaticResource` markup extension you should get an exception if the "BaseSliderStyle" cannot be found. You can switch back to using `DynamicResource` when you have confirmed that the style is found and is being applied as expected.

Also note that I am using a merged `ResourceDictionary` and a pack URI to specify the source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx.

Please also make sure that that the resource dictionary is actually called "BaseSliderStyle.xaml" and that is located under a folder called "Styles" at the root of the project/assembly called "WPFUserControls".